# Rails, Why when I assign an object, an update statement is executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4 and when I assign the result of a sql statement to an object, an update is performed. How can I avoid this?

my models are basically:

```
class Tarifa < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :disponibilidads
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :disponibilidads
end

class Disponibilidad < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :tarifa
end
```

my controller (DisponibilidadsController).
Here between the 'step 10' and 'step 11' marks is the problem.

```
@tarifa = Tarifa.find(@tarifa_id)
disp = Disponibilidad.where(where_sentencia, where_param).order("fecha")

puts "step 10 " 
@tarifa.disponibilidads = disp
puts “step 11”
```

and if i look in the rails console

```
step 10

Disponibilidad Load (186.1ms)  SELECT `disponibilidads`.* FROM `disponibilidads` 
WHERE (tarifa_id = 1 AND fecha >= '2013-10-01' AND fecha <= '2013-10-31') 
ORDER BY fecha

Disponibilidad Load (347.8ms)  SELECT `disponibilidads`.* FROM `disponibilidads`
WHERE `disponibilidads`.`tarifa_id` = 1

(174.0ms)  BEGIN

SQL (178.2ms)  UPDATE `disponibilidads` SET `disponibilidads`.`tarifa_id` = NULL 
WHERE `disponibilidads`.`tarifa_id` = 1 AND `disponibilidads`.`id` IN (1700,
1701,1702, 1703, 1704, 1705, 1706, 1707, 1708, 1709, 1710, 1711, 1712, 1713, 
1714, 1715, 1716, 1717, 1718, 1719, 1720, 1721, 1722, 1723, 1724, 1725, 1726, 
1727, 1728, 1729)

(172.4ms)  COMMIT

step 11
```

how can I avoid this update?  I just need to assign the object 'disp' a '@ tarifa.disponibilidads' then iterate in view

in the view, i have a simple_nested_fomr_for. (and it's works )

```
 <%= simple_nested_form_for @tarifa, url: disponibilidads_path  do |f| %>
```

with some typical hidden fields from the paretn object, and when I need to iterate over the children objects:

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :disponibilidads, :wrapper => false do |disp| %>
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE: finally solved, like comments said,  in this way:

on the CONTROLLER, use separate objects for the father-object (Tarifa) and child-object (Disponibilidad).

```
@tarifa = Tarifa.find(@tarifa_id)
@disponibilidades = Disponibilidad.where(where_sentencia, where_param).order(":fecha")
```

in the view, using the same nested forms, change this: ":wrapper => false"

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :disponibilidads, :wrapper => false do |disp| %>
```

for this: "@disponibilidades"

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :disponibilidads, @disponibilidades do |disp| %>
```

there is another way to do it, without putting objects into separate parent and child variables, for this we can create in the model Dispomibilidads, a kind of filter:

```
class Disponibilidad < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tarifa

    scope :filtro_fecha, lambda { |inicio, fin| where("fecha >= :inicio AND fecha <= :fin", {:inicio => inicio, :fin => fin}) }

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disponibilidads is in a one to many relationship with tarifa, therefore, when you assign something through the relationship rails needs to track the result, which is what it's doing.  This is by design, of course.

If all you want to do is display `disp` in your view, then just store that in a variable and don't create the relationship.

`@disps = Disponibilidad.where(where_sentencia, where_param).order("fecha")`

Comment: i'll see if i can put the separate variable into the simple_nested_form to use in the view

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) `collection=objects` method replaces collection immediately. If you really need to assign association without saving it immediately you can use [deferred_associations](https://github.com/MartinKoerner/deferred_associations) gem. But i think it would be better idea to use another variable to display `disponibilidads` in view

Comment: I may be missing something about models management have rails and the correct way to use them -  I'm really new to rails, aobut the idea of user another variable, i think it not works because I am using a 'simple_nested_form' to iterate the parent object and then iterate each child object and letting rails automatically take care of saving the modified variables.  Im going to put some of the code i using in the view...